# Is there any interference between borlndmm.dll Access Violation and UAC/run as Administrator?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I have ported project from Delphi 6 to Delphi XE7. That exe in some circumstances gives an Access Violation in module Borlndmm.dll. I found that when exe is runnig as an Administrator or UAC is turned off - there is no error. 
Project uses Sharemem because of some dll that needs it.

Is there any link between that Borlndmm.dll and user privileges on Windows 7?

Comment: The likely explanation is a bug in your code

Comment: So, my guess is that you now have a manifest in your executable and so your application is no longer virtualized. Incidentally, UAC is 10 years old and you should have got on top of these issues a long time ago. The fact that the D6 IDE pre-dated Vista is no reason for you not putting a manifest in your exe. Anyway, now that you are not virtualized, non-admin users will encounter failures when you write to the program files folder, or the system dirs, or HKLM or whatever erroneous thing your program does. And that's your error.

Comment: But I'm just guessing. This is a plausible explanation. However, since you've provided no real detail all we can do is make guesses. Your next move is to learn all about UAC and how it affects developers. Until you do that, and really understand it properly, you'll just be wasting time.

Comment: Try BorlandMM.DLL from FastMM4 project, there are few - take the one compiled to gather full debug info. It must have been  bug in your memory, either feeding wrong pointers to it, or destroying heap allocation information structure.

As a general rule - try to remove this library altogether, there is no need to use it now, there is SimpleShareMem unit instead achieveing this without DLLs